# Make script write to root directory instead of module directory

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to make my script write a file to the root directory instead of the module directory

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, dir, "file.txt"), this.config);
```

but no matter what I try it makes it in the module directory.

Comment: `fs.writeFileSync("/file.txt", this.config);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run your program from your root directory (the root of your project folder?), you might want to use [`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd):

```
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(process.cwd(), "file.txt"), this.config);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful, I was just missing the 'dir' part and now it works perfectly.